# Pandas adding row at index 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with one row, like so:

```
               Player      Team  Points  Mean  Price  Value
Round                                                              
1              Salah  Liverpool     4.5    4.5   6.89  1.89
```

Now I need to add a dummy column at index 0 with an open price 'Price' = 5.0, obtained by `df['Price'] - df['Value']`, and all other column values set to `0.0`, ending up with, like so:

```
               Player      Team  Points  Mean  Price  Value
Round
0              Salah  Liverpool     0.0    0.0   5.0    0.0                        
1              Salah  Liverpool     4.5    4.5   6.89  1.89
```

---

```
atleta_data.loc[-1] = [df['Player'].item(), 
                       df['Team'].item(),
                       0.0, 
                       0.0, 
                       (df['Price'].item() - df['Value'].item()), 
                       0.0]  
atleta_data.index = atleta_data.index +1  # shifting index
atleta_data = atleta_data.sort_index()  # sorting by index
```

But I'm getting Rounds 0 and 2.

```
              Player      Team  Points  Mean  Price  Value
Round
0              Salah  Liverpool     0.0    0.0   5.0    0.0                        
2              Salah  Liverpool     4.5    4.5   6.89  1.89
```

How can I end up with 0 and 1 for Rounds?

Comment: try `.reset_index()`

Comment: you can answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
atleta_data = atleta_data.sort_index().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
l = [df['Player'].item(), 
                       df['Team'].item(),
                       0.0, 
                       0.0, 
                       (df['Price'].item() - df['Value'].item()), 
                       0.0]

pd.DataFrame([l],columns=df.columns,index=[0]).append(df)
Out[127]: 
  Player       Team  Points  Mean  Price  Value
0  Salah  Liverpool     0.0   0.0   5.00   0.00
1  Salah  Liverpool     4.5   4.5   6.89   1.89
```